# Microscopic explanation of the magnetic force

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, quantum-spin

I was recently reading about magnetic force. Although its macroscopic functioning is clear, no microscopic explanation of how it works seemed clear to me. The spin concept, for example, seems illogical and  counter intuitive. Starting from primitive concepts like the basic atomic structure, is there any way to explain the microscopic functioning of the magnetic force?

Comment: You are going to need to elaborate what is illogical to you since spin is the basic atomic concept. I tend to just think of it as: moving charges make magnetic fields, like current in an electromagnet, and electrons "spinning" counts as a way in which a charge can move.

Comment: The origin of the magnetic force from moving charges is indeed mysterious. So is the origin of the electric force from the mere presence of charge. So is the origin of gravity. Unfortunately our intuition has a hard time wrapping itself around fundamental forces and concepts.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd quite classify 'basic atomic structure' as a 'primitive concept'...